# Linux Ubuntu error

Tags: linux, ubuntu

How do I fix the following error

```
 > [stage-1  7/11] RUN     addgroup --system -gid ${TOR_LINUX_GID} tor &&         adduser --system --ingroup tor -uid ${TOR_LINUX_UID} tor:                                     
#0 0.333 Value "tor" invalid for option gid (number expected)                                                                                                                   
#0 0.333 adduser [--home DIR] [--shell SHELL] [--no-create-home] [--uid ID]                                                                                                     
#0 0.333 [--firstuid ID] [--lastuid ID] [--gecos GECOS] [--ingroup GROUP | --gid ID]                                                                                            
#0 0.333 [--disabled-password] [--disabled-login] [--add_extra_groups] USER
#0 0.333    Add a normal user
#0 0.333 
#0 0.333 adduser --system [--home DIR] [--shell SHELL] [--no-create-home] [--uid ID]
#0 0.333 [--gecos GECOS] [--group | --ingroup GROUP | --gid ID] [--disabled-password]
#0 0.333 [--disabled-login] [--add_extra_groups] USER
#0 0.333    Add a system user
#0 0.333 
#0 0.333 adduser --group [--gid ID] GROUP
#0 0.333 addgroup [--gid ID] GROUP
#0 0.333    Add a user group
#0 0.333 
#0 0.333 addgroup --system [--gid ID] GROUP
#0 0.333    Add a system group
#0 0.333 
#0 0.333 adduser USER GROUP
#0 0.333    Add an existing user to an existing group
#0 0.333 
#0 0.333 general options:
#0 0.333   --quiet | -q      don't give process information to stdout
#0 0.333   --force-badname   allow usernames which do not match the
#0 0.333                     NAME_REGEX configuration variable
#0 0.333   --help | -h       usage message
#0 0.333   --version | -v    version number and copyright
#0 0.333   --conf | -c FILE  use FILE as configuration file
#0 0.333 
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c addgroup --system -gid ${TOR_LINUX_GID} tor &&         adduser --system --ingroup tor -uid ${TOR_LINUX_UID} tor" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
[+] Running 5/5
 ! tor Warning                                                                                                                                                             3.1s 
 ! fulcrum Warning                                                                                                                                                         3.0s 
 ! bitcoind Warning                                                                                                                                                        3.0s 
 ! nginx Warning                                                                                                                                                           3.1s 
 ! node Warning                                                                                                                                                            3.1s 
[+] Building 1.1s (15/19)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the variable ${TOR_LINUX_GID} is empty and what is running is actually:

```
/bin/sh -c addgroup --system -gid tor
```

Since "tor" is not a number you get the error:

"Value "tor" invalid for option gid (number expected)"

Fix is to give more information i.e. why/where you run those commands, check why the variable is empty and maybe run the command with more verbosity.